# Wrong coordinates on multi touch with onTouchEvent android

Tags: android, touch-event

I have an issue with the input in my game. In my game, there is a joystick and two buttons. I've overwritten the onTouchEvent method for input. The onTouchEvent changes a few variables which another method in the class processes.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean touched = false;
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touched = true;
            if ((event.getX() < Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                xPos = Math.round(event.getX());
                yPos = Math.round(event.getY());
                joystickPressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                button1Pressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY() < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                button2Pressed = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touched = true;
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) < Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                xPos = Math.round(event.getX());
                yPos = Math.round(event.getY());
                joystickPressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                button1Pressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY() < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                button2Pressed = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                button1Pressed = false;
            } else if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY() < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                button2Pressed = false;
            } else {
                xPos = Math.round(Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density);
                yPos = Math.round(Data.width - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density);
                joystickPressed = false;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                button1Pressed = false;
            } else if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY() < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                button2Pressed = false;
            } else {
                xPos = Math.round(Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density);
                yPos = Math.round(Data.width - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density);
                joystickPressed = false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return touched || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

However there appears to be a problem. The code works fine when there is only a single pointer on the screen, or the joystick is pressed first. But when one of the button is pressed first, the code appears to give the wrong coordinates for the joystick's xPos and yPos. Also when the joystick is moved it appears to affect the buttons.

What is the problem in my code? Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean touched = false;
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touched = true;
            if ((event.getX() < Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                xPos = Math.round(event.getX());
                yPos = Math.round(event.getY());
                joystickPressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                shootPressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY() < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                superpunchPressed = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touched = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); ++i){
                if ((event.getX(i) < Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(i) > (Data.height - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                    xPos = event.getX(i);
                    yPos = event.getY(i);
                    joystickPressed = true;
                }
                if ((event.getX(i) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(i) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                    shootPressed = true;
                }
                if ((event.getX(i) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(i) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY(i) < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                    superpunchPressed = true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touched = true;
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) < Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                xPos = event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
                yPos = event.getY(event.getActionIndex());
                joystickPressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                shootPressed = true;
            }
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                superpunchPressed = true;
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                shootPressed = false;
            } else if ((event.getX() > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY() > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY() < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                superpunchPressed = false;
            } else {
                xPos = Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density;
                yPos = Data.width - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density;
                joystickPressed = false;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density))) {
                shootPressed = false;
            } else if ((event.getX(event.getActionIndex()) > Data.width - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) > (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density * 2 - 20 * Data.density)) && (event.getY(event.getActionIndex()) < (Data.height - Constants.BUTTON_SIZE * Data.density - 20 * Data.density))) {
                superpunchPressed = false;
            } else {
                xPos = Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density;
                yPos = Data.width - Constants.JOYSTICK_SIZE / 2 * Data.density;
                joystickPressed = false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return touched || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the correct touch points like this in your onTouch event.

```
    float xPos = event.getRawX()-v.getX();
    float yPos = event.getRawY()-v.getY();
```

Comment: the view on which you have set you touch listener

Comment: Welcome. i have used it with imageview. Works perfect.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, something else must be wrong.